# monit won't mount filesystem with "execution failed", works manually

Tags: monit

I have monit configured to mount an NFS filesystem if it is ever not mounted, however for some reason monit won't mount the share automatically and I have to run `monit start myshare` in order to get the filesystem mounted.

The system often can't mount NFS shares at boot time (as the remote system is typically booting at the same time and isn't up yet) which is why I want monit to keep retrying the mount, which will eventually succeed when the remote system finishes booting.

However it seems that monit just gives up too soon and stops trying, meaning I have to manually run `monit start myshare` in order to get it to try again.  This always succeeds, suggesting the `start` command in `monitrc` is correct.

I can see in the monit manual how to limit a service so that it will stop trying after a certain number of failures, but I can't see how to disable this so it just keeps trying forever.

Here is my `monitrc`:

```
set daemon 30
set log syslog
set mailserver ...
check filesystem myshare with path /mnt/myshare
        start program = "/bin/mount /mnt/myshare"
        group nfs
```

And this is what it says after booting the machine:

```
$ monit status myshare
Filesystem 'myshare'           
  status                       Execution failed
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  filesystem type              nfs

$ monit start myshare
$ monit status myshare
Monit 5.25.1 uptime: 5d 10h 32m

Filesystem 'myshare'
  status                       OK
  monitoring status            Monitored
  monitoring mode              active
  on reboot                    start
  filesystem type              nfs
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for a flag file available only when the mount is ok like and retry on a regular basis

`check file myshare-flag with path /mnt/myshare/my-flag-file
      if does not exist then exec "/bin/mount /mnt/myshare" repeat every 2 cycles`

Checking a flag file is better as the file will only be present when mount is working.